# Can't execute installer from Shared Folders on non-domain Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, network-share, file-permissions, share, shared-folders

On a non-domain Windows Server 2012 x64 vm, I have a shared folder with an installer. Whenever I try to run this installer from any workstation, the workstation's account on the server is locked.

I shared a folder by by doing the following:
Right click on the folder and select properties > Select the Sharing tab > Click the Advanced Sharing button > Checked Share this folder > Clicked Permissions > Gave Full Control to everyone. This didn't work. I also clicked the Share button under the Sharing Tab and added Everyone with read/write permissions. This still didn't help.

Please help me share a folder that can execute an installer from without locking the user from the server. It worked in Windows Server 2008 but not in Server 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect this is UAC.  If so, the following should work:

1. Launch a command line on the workstation as an administrator.
2. Map the network drive from the elevated command line.
3. Run the installer from the elevated command line.